# ESLint for TS no-unused-vars for class and injections

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

Can I configure @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars rule that it ignore such code?

example 1

```
export default class MyClass .... {}
```

example 2

```
import { injection } from 'any_package';

@injection()
class MyClass
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: MyClass  is defined but never used

Comment: Maybe it's never imported anywhere? I'm pretty sure *no-unused-vars* does ignore exported variables by default - if not, that's a bug

Comment: That's right, exported classes are ignored anyway. But example 2 still needs a solution.

Comment: if I write class MyClass {} and after that export default MyClass, eslint don't show warn

Comment: But I wouldn't like change over 100 files manually

Comment: Case 2 is hard. Ostensibly, `MyClass` *is* unused, regardless whether it was created with a decorator or not. The linter cannot know that the `@injection()` decorator does put the class in a global registry. (Assuming that is what it does?)

Comment: yeah, you are right, the case 2 is hard.

Comment: I would recommend you switch to `register(class MyClass { … });`, the linter should not complain about that. Otherwise you'll probably have to customise the plugin yourself, making it ignore variables that are decorated with `@injection()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
What you can recommend about first example?

Comment: Didn't you just say that it works and exported classes are ignored?

Comment: yep, but I would not like to change all files

Comment: Change what? `export default class MyClass { … }` is fine

Comment: yep
replace export default class MyClass { … } to class MyClass { … } export default MyClass

Comment: I wrote in varsIgnorePattern this regex expression "(?<=export default class\\s)\\w+". Why it doesn't work? If I write just MyClass, it will be work for MyClass fine

Comment: `varIgnorePatterns` is a pattern matching against the variable name, not the whole declaration

Comment: If `export default class MyClass { … }` does not work, please report this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its clever to define a global rule in your ESLint config for such a case since it probably doesn't occur that often. You can use a comment to disable/ignore the following line like so:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
class MyClass .... {}
```

If you really want to add a global rule to your `.eslintrc.json` you could define a [`varsIgnorePattern`](https://%7B%20%20%20%22parser%22:%20%22@typescript-eslint/parser%22,%20%20%20%22plugins%22:%20%5B%22@typescript-eslint%22%5D,%20%20%20%22extends%22:%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%22eslint:recommended%22,%20%20%20%20%20%22plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended%22%20%20%20%5D,%20%20%20%22rules%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20//%20Your%20other%20rules%20here%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%22overrides%22:%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22files%22:%20%5B%22*.ts%22,%20%22*.tsx%22%5D,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22rules%22:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars%22:%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22error%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22varsIgnorePattern%22:%20%22MyClass%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%5D%20%7D) for `@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`.

Example `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    // Your other rules here
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": [
          "error",
          {
            "varsIgnorePattern": "MyClass" // <- regexp pattern 
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: that's great, but I have more the 100 files with the same error, so I would like a common solution
RegEpx pattern I think a good solution, but I don't know regexp expression a very well